# Turn picture in Black or white. How?

Tags: image, python-3.7, rgb

I want to write a function that changes my RGB picture in black OR white, not in grayscale. 
I should only use NumPy functions for this. I want that the RGB below a certain threshold changes into black [0 0 0], and above a certain threshold white [255 255 255].
How to make a function where each pixel of an image is rounded up or down?
dtype = 'uint8'.
I've  uploaded a picture to python by doing this: `img = mpimg.imread('Picture.png')`

And, a further question, how to write function that turns half of the pixels into black, and half of the pixels into white? (using numpy.median)

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/233340/display-image-from-live-webcam-as-taken-with-four-different-color-filters-and-i      Hope the link will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = np.random.rand(64,64,3)*255

threshold = 100
b = (a > threshold)*255
```

You can use operators such as `>` on numpy arrays to generate boolean arrays which indicate for which cells the condition is true or false (the threshold). You can then multiply this boolean array with what you want the result of your threshold to be (in this case 255 and 0).

Comment: So by using np.random.rand you go over the picture? Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: np.random is just for me to generate an "RGB image" size 64x64x3. In your case a would be your image.